# WOW js animation repeat not working

Tags: html, css, animation, repeat, wow.js

I'm using wow.js for some animations on my website and it's working great, but I'd prefer it to re-animate every time someone scrolls past it.

I checked everywhere online and I've tried the code snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187211/wow-js-repeat-animation-every-time-you-scroll-up-or-down), but it doesn't seem to work.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: one of the answers from that link works... https://jsfiddle.net/ugurerkan/53641ovn/

Comment: @WilliamB Thank you! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The creator of WOW.js did not add this feature. However; this can be achieved with the help of js scrollspy plugin.